# Use of unresolved identifier `displayMessage`

Tags: swift

[Here is my error by image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uX2jE.png)

My code is below and I have all problems on `displayMessage`

First error is:

> SigninViewController.swift:45:17: Use of unresolved identifier 'displayMessage'

Next error is:

> SigninViewController.swift:87:13: Value of type 'SigninViewController' has no member 'removeActivityIndicator'

```
import UIKit

class SigninViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var userNameTextFeild: UITextField!


    @IBOutlet weak var userPasswordTextField: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func loginInButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        print("log in button tapped")

        //Read values from text field

        let userName = userNameTextFeild.text
        let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text

    // Check if required fields are not empty
        if(userName?.isEmpty)! || (userPassword?.isEmpty)!
        {

        // Display alert message


                print("User name \(String(describing: userName)) or password \(String(describing:userPassword)) is empty")

                displayMessage(userMessage:"one of the required feilds is missing")

                return

        }
        // Activity indicator

        let myActivityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray)

        myActivityIndicator.center = view.center

        myActivityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = false

        myActivityIndicator.startAnimating()

        view.addSubview(myActivityIndicator)


        // URL for login

        let myUrl = URL(string: "htps://198.228.12.1")
        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let postString = ["userName": userName!, "userPassword": userPassword!] as [String:String]

        do {
            request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postString,
               options: .prettyPrinted)
        } catch let error  {
            print(error.localizedDescription)

            displayMessage(userMessage:"something went wrong")

            return
        }

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, responce:
            URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
            self.removeActivityIndicator(activityIndicator: myActivityIndicator)

            if error != nil
            {


                self.displayMessage(userMessage: "Could not sucessfully perform this request")
                print("error=\(String(describing:error))")
                return

        }
            do{
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

            } catch {

                self.remoteActivityIndicator(activityIndicator: myActivityIndicator)


                self.displayMessage(userMessage: "Could not sucessfully perform this request")
                print(error)



      }

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you really need to break up your code into functions. That will make it much easier to debug, because you will know exactly which function is not functioning correctly.

The JSON request should be one function, parsing the JSON should be another, and if you need to update the screen that should be another.

Now for your error, I don't see where `displayMessage` is initialized (or defined), so you need to create it before it can be used.